# Javascript / Node.js importing html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm making a node.js server which sends emails on demand. The variable "output" is what I want to send via email. When I use inline html it works fine, however I want to import a complete html file instead.

I've tried using <object> and <link> to import "file.html" which is in the same folder as app.js, but both show up as a white page.

```
app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
    console.log("sending email...");
    const email = req.body.data.email;
    const customerId = req.body.data.customer_id;
    const orderId = req.body.data.order_id;

    //const output = `<h3>Hi, this works</h3>` // WORKS
    //const output = `<object type="text/html" data="file.html"></object>`; // Doesn't work
    const output = `<link href="file.html" rel="import" />`;                    // Doesn't work
;
```

Help is much appreciated. I can supply more code if necessary.

Comment: Read the file into memory and store it in a variable. The html inside your output variable is not parsedd which is why your file is never included.

Comment: @t348575 Oh makes sense, I'm not that fluent in Node.js yet, could you show how to do that or point me in the right direction? Would I use require('..') for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this outside your .post method so that it is run once when your program starts and output is populated instead of reading the file every time your .post or .get method is called

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const output = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.html').toString();
```